# Ethernet to HDMI output

Tags: server, hdmi, video

I have an HP proliant micro server sitting in my home office and I want to stream photos and videos off this device and display it on my TV in another room.  The TV also sits next to an ethernet hub and my preference is to connect the TV to network via this hub.

What I am looking for is an output device that will sit on the network to talk to the server and provide an HDMI/1080p output to the TV.   I am currently planning on using [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org) on the serve up the data, (but I am not bound to that), so the solution would need to be able to browse/select the media to play.

I also don't need this device to do anything else other than serve up data from the NAS.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some consideration I am going with Plex layered on top of FreeNAS, and using a Chromecast for the HDMI head end and using the Plex/Chromcast App on my tablet to perform the control.